# How to display a 3D object in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I've read the A-Frame documentation and copied the code directly from it, but I'm having trouble displaying a 3D object in .obj and .mtl formats. This is what I have:

```
<a-assets>
<a-asset-item id="chair-obj" src="obj/chair1.obj"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="chair-mtl" src="obj/chair1.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<a-entity obj-model="obj: #chair-obj; mtl: #chair-mtl" position="0 1 -1" scale="0.000001 0.000001 0.000001"></a-entity>
```

The documentation suggests this might be a problem with mis-matched scales between A-Frame's scale and the object's native scale. It suggests scaling it down so I did so in steps from 0.1 to 0.000001 but still cannot see the object displayed (the object, and other test objects, were downloaded from TurboSquid but none display).

Answer (score 2):

I've used slightly different syntax which worked for me: `<a-obj-model src="#chair-obj" mtl="#chair-mtl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"></a-obj-model>`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work although I'm not sure if it was your code or the fact that I updated the A-Frame version from 0.2 to 0.3. But now I see the object!